# Alternative for Xephyr in wayland

Tags: linux, wayland

I'm searching for a tool to test my codes, I always do it using Xephyr for Xorg.
Now Is there any alternative for Xephyr in Wayland?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Be sure to read their help section to compose a Q that people will be able to answer. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Wayland environments like Gnome 3 or KDE 5 use a rootless Xwayland to support X applications; Xephyr still works then.

For pure Wayland environments there is currently no nested X server available, afaik. Xpra may support this as soon as it is ported to GTK3 and python 3. But that port is not ready yet.

For now, you can run Xwayland as a Wayland client (not rootless in this case). With given environment variables `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` and `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, you can run `Xwayland :1` and start X applications with `DISPLAY=:1 xterm`.

Xwayland appears as a fullscreen borderless window. Unfortunately, it is not possible to set another screen size for Xwayland. In Gnome 3 you can move it around with SUPER+LeftMouseButton,  other Wayland compositors may have a different setup to move borderless clients. Instead of moving Xwayland window, you can use ALT+Tab in many desktop environments to switch to the hidden applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly an interesting option that may do what you need to do with some systemd-nspawn and kwin_wayland magic.

https://github.com/ken-okabe/wayland-desktop-container